# How to insert checkbox count into database and display that count in view in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to code igniter.I'm trying to count the selected checkbox and insert that count into database and display that count in view. My code is
Model:

```
$count = count($this->input->post('checkbox'));
    $data=array(
        'count'=>$count
    );
     $this->db->insert('employees',$data);
```

By submitting the form it automatically create new row in database and print that count. Plase help me that count which is print for particular id in database.

Comment: Please share the form to be submitted.

Comment: To update the data you have to use update function. (Not insert). Please check this codeigniter [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data).

Comment: I am using update but all rows are updating.

Answer (score 0):

Try sizeof instead of count

```
$count = sizeof($this->input->post('checkbox'));
$data=array(
    'count'=>$count
);
 $this->db->insert('employees',$data);
```

Comment: I want to develop an employee attendance system

Comment: I want to develop an employee attendance system. It includes check boxes beside the employee name and i want to display the count of checked one's after submission.

Comment: You are maintaining employee attendance in single database table or in master detail table ?

Comment: I am maintaining single database table.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you should use radio buttons instead of check boxes. Only 1 radio button will be checked for 1 employee
Here is some Example Code in your controller I hope This will help you.

```
$post_date = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
$emp_id_array = $post_date['emp_id'];
$attendance = $post_date['attendance_flag'];
$attendance_data = [];
foreach ($attendance as $key => $value) {
                $row_data['EMP_ID'] = $emp_id_array[$key];
                $row_data['ATD_FLAG'] = $attendance[$key];
                $attendance_data[] = $row_data;
        }
```

in your model just call insert_batch. This will insert data in bulk

```
 $this->db->insert_batch('yourtable', $attendance_data);
```